# from where IE browser picks JRE to use

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

I would like to know how Internet Explorer picks the JRE version. When I load an applet through browser, how does browser decides to use which JRE version when there are multiple JRE installed on the machine?
Does IE browser always picks latest version of JRE, or it can use a lower version which is installed on the machine?

Comment: from the PATH and JAVA_HOME in environment variables

Comment: I don't have PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables set on my machine. But still my IE select jre form some where ? does it read from registry to decide which version to use?

Answer (score 0):

Latest version is picked in principle, but JRE family version is specified and it matches the security baseline, IE can use a lower version.

For example, if 1.8.0_45 and 1.7.0_80 are installed, IE can use Java7 and Java8. But if 1.8.0_45 and 1.7.0_71, only Java8 is available.

[Deploying Java Applets With Family JRE Versions in Java Plug-in for Internet Explorer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/family-clsid-140615.html)